# Can flash messages like these be created in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo, messagebox

[image: Something like the red circle at the bottom]

I'm a beginner in react-native. So, I searched through Google but there wasn't any method to create the message like above. If someone has found out a way, please help...

Comment: I don't understand the question well, could you rephrase it please?

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad explanation. I just wanted to know if we can make flash messages like the one in the pic in react-native.@JoelJaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Toast".
Please beware that it is an Android feature and doesn't exist on ios (they have something similar, don't remember it name.

You can see the React-Native [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/toastandroid) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tiny-toast
use this library you can shape it the way you want with styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `npm` package: [react-native-simple-toast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-toast) which is supported by both of the platforms i.e. android and iOS and is currently being maintained by its maintainers.